# How to solve an ODE of this form $\dot{P}(t)=A^TP(t)+P(t)A$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, lyapunov-functions

**Background**

If $\dot{x}(t)=A \,x(t)$, then we know the solution is $x(t)=e^{At}x(0)$.

**Question**

Now let $\dot{P}(t)=A^TP(t)+P(t)A$, what is $P(t)$?

**Attempt**

If we take $P(t)$ as common factor (I'm not sure I'm doing this correctly though) ,then we have: 
$$
\dot{P}(t)=A^TP(t)+P(t)A=(A^T+A)P(t)
$$ 
and using the same rationale in the background section, we have 
$$
P(t)=e^{(A^T+A) t}P(0)=e^{A^T t}P(0)e^{At}
$$
Is this a correct solution?

**Note**

I know the answer is $P(t)=e^{A^T t}P(0)e^{At}$ but I'm not sure how to find it.

Comment: Counter question: what is A?

Comment: @YuriyS A is a matrix.

Comment: Dimensions are very likely mismatched in the expression $\dot{p}(t)=A^Tp(t)+p(t)A$.

Comment: What is $p A$ then?

Comment: @Ennar I fixed the question.

Comment: @YuriyS $P$ is a matrix too. I fixed the question.

Comment: I don't really see it. Could you write explicitly what $A$ and $P$ are? Like, not just "matrix", its dimensions.

Comment: Your attempt has issues. The solutions for $P_1,P_2$ are not correct

Comment: @Ennar This ODE is the same as the so-called _Lyapunov equation_ which is $A^TP+PA=-Q$ where $P$ and $Q$ are symmetric positive-definite matrices. All the matrices are in $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$.

Comment: My advice: write down your equations explicitly for small dimensions (like $2 \times 2$) and see how they can be solved componentwise

Comment: @YuriyS I mean I'm seeking a way to find something similar to the solution of the equation I wrote in the background section. How is it that we know the solution to $\dot{x}(t)=A \,x(t)$ is $x(t)=e^{At}x(0)$? This is something that people write directly when solving an ODE of such form. I'm not sure how is it derived though.

Comment: @Lod, then I would suggest you look up any text on linear systems of ODEs and study the derivation of this formula. Then you might get the necessary instruments to approach your more complicated problem

Comment: @YuriyS Thank you, however my main concern is solutions of ODEs in general. I am just utilizing this in a control theory problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84547/discussion-between-yuriy-s-and-lod).

Answer (score 2):

Consider the differential equation
$$
\dot{P}(t)=A^TP(t)+P(t)A
$$

We can rewrite it as:
$$
\dot{P}(\tau)-A^TP(\tau)-P(\tau)A=0
$$

Multiply the last differential equation by $e^{-A^T\tau}$ from the left and by $e^{-A\tau}$ from the right then

\begin{equation}
e^{-A^T\tau}\dot{P}(\tau)e^{-A\tau}-e^{-A^T\tau}A^TP(\tau)e^{-A\tau}-e^{-A^T\tau}P(\tau)Ae^{-A\tau}=0 \quad (1)
\end{equation}
We can easily see that equation $(1)$ is generated by the derivative of three multiplied functions:
 \begin{equation}
\frac{d}{d\tau}\bigg(e^{-A^T\tau}{P}(\tau)e^{-A\tau}\bigg)=e^{-A^T\tau}\dot{P}(\tau)e^{-A\tau}-A^Te^{-A^T\tau}P(\tau)e^{-A\tau}-e^{-A^T\tau}P(\tau)Ae^{-A\tau}=0
\end{equation}

So we come up with:

$0=\frac{d}{d\tau}\bigg(e^{-A^T\tau}{P}(\tau)e^{-A\tau}\bigg)$

Take the integral of both sides

\begin{equation}
0=\int_0^t\frac{d}{d\tau}\bigg(e^{-A^T\tau}{P}(\tau)e^{-A\tau}\bigg)d\tau=\bigg(e^{-A^T\tau}{P}(\tau)e^{-A\tau}\bigg)\bigg]_0^t=e^{-A^Tt}{P} \tau)e^{-At}-e^{0}{P}(0)e^{0}\end{equation}
 \
\begin{equation}
0=e^{-A^Tt}{P}(t)e^{-At}-P(0)
\end{equation}

Multiply left and right sides by $e^{A^Tt}$ and $e^{At}$ respectively, we get:

\begin{equation}
P(t)=e^{A^Tt}{P}(0)e^{At}
\end{equation}

Note: I used the fact that $e^{-A^T\tau}$ and $A^T$ commute, i.e. $A^Te^{-A^T\tau}=e^{-A^T\tau}A^T$

Answer (score 1):

For small time increment you get approximately
$$
P(t+dt)=P(t)+(A^TP(t)+P(t)A)dt+O(dt^2)=(I+A^T\,dt)P(t)(I+A\,dt)+O(dt^2)
$$
which means that from time step to time step you get an accumulation of these factors on both sides,
$$
P(N\,dt)=(I+A^T\,dt)^NP(t)(I+A\,dt)^N+O(Ndt^2)
$$
Now if $N\,dt=\Delta t$ we get, using $(I+B/N)^N=\exp(B)+O(B^2/N)$
$$
P(t+Δt)=e^{A^T\,Δt}P(t)e^{A\,Δt}+O(Δt\,dt)
$$
so that for $dt\to 0$ one gets exactly the claimed solution form.

Answer (score 1):

By vectorizing $P$ and using the Kronecker product, similar to a method which can be used to solve [Sylvester equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), then the differential equation can also be written as

$$
\frac{d}{dt}\,\text{vec}\,P(t) = \underbrace{\left(I \otimes A^\top + A^\top\otimes I\right)}_{M}\,\text{vec}\,P(t), \tag{1}
$$

which has the solution

$$
\text{vec}\,P(t) = e^{M\,t}\,\text{vec}\,P(0). \tag{2}
$$

By using the [mixed-product property of the Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Relations_to_other_matrix_operations) it can be shown that $I \otimes A^\top$ commutes with $A^\top \otimes I$. This commuting property allows you to write the matrix exponential as

$$
e^{M\,t} = e^{(I\,\otimes\,A^\top)\,t}\,e^{(A^\top\,\otimes\,I)\,t}. \tag{3}
$$

By using the definition of a [matrix exponential](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MatrixExponential.html) and again the mixed-product property of the Kronecker product then is can also be shown that

$$
e^{X\,\otimes\,I} = e^{X} \otimes I, \quad
e^{I\,\otimes\,X} = I \otimes e^{X},
$$

thus

$$
e^{M\,t} = \left(I \otimes e^{A^\top t}\right) \left(e^{A^\top t} \otimes I\right). \tag{4}
$$

Substituting $(4)$ into $(2)$ gives

\begin{align}
\text{vec}\,P(t) &= \left(I \otimes e^{A^\top t}\right) \left(e^{A^\top t} \otimes I\right) \text{vec}\,P(0) \\
&= \left(I \otimes e^{A^\top t}\right) \text{vec}\left(P(0)\,e^{A\,t}\right) \\
&= \text{vec}\left(e^{A^\top t}\,P(0)\,e^{A\,t}\right)
\end{align}

thus

$$
P(t) = e^{A^\top t}\,P(0)\,e^{A\,t}.
$$